# how define a new column with 2 group and 1 column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 3 columns:

```
household   persons   activity
  1       1        home
  1       1         shopping
  1       1        home
  1       1         eating
  1       1         work
  1       1        shopping
  1       1         home
  1       2         home
  1       2          shopping
  1       2         home
  2       1         home
  2       1         eating
  2       1         home
```

the first column is household index and the second household members.each activity for each person starts at home. Foe each person in each family I want to defend a column loop, it starts from 1 and change to loop+1 when the activity is a activity after home or work. For example in the following data the third row is home so we have loop=2 for 4-th row and 5-th row is work so we have loop=3 after work

output

```
household   persons   activity      loop
  1       1        home               1
  1       1         shopping          1 
  1       1        home               1
  1       1         eating            2
  1       1         work              2
  1       1        shopping           3
  1       1         home              3
  1       2         home              1 
  1       2          shopping         1
  1       2         home              1
  2       1         home              1
  2       1         eating            1
  2       1         home              1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one idea. We can use the `rleid`, `fill`, and `lead` function to create the `loop` column

```
dat2 <- dat %>%
  mutate(activity2 = replace(activity, !activity %in% c("home", "work"), NA)) %>%
  group_by(household, persons) %>%
  fill(activity2) %>%
  mutate(loop = lead(rleid(activity2))) %>%
  fill(loop) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-activity2)
dat2  
# # A tibble: 13 x 4
#    household persons activity  loop
#        <int>   <int> <chr>    <int>
#  1         1       1 home         1
#  2         1       1 shopping     1
#  3         1       1 home         1
#  4         1       1 eating       2
#  5         1       1 work         2
#  6         1       1 shopping     3
#  7         1       1 home         3
#  8         1       2 home         1
#  9         1       2 shopping     1
# 10         1       2 home         1
# 11         2       1 home         1
# 12         2       1 eating       1
# 13         2       1 home         1
```

**Data**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "household   persons   activity
  1       1        home
  1       1         shopping
  1       1        home
  1       1         eating
  1       1         work
  1       1        shopping
  1       1         home
  1       2         home
  1       2          shopping
  1       2         home
  2       1         home
  2       1         eating
  2       1         home",
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE)
```

Comment: You said "change when the activity is home or work." 6th row is shopping, which is not home or work, so no need to change based on your rule.

Comment: it changes at work and it doesn't change until next work or home, or end of data row for that person

Comment: in 5-th row we have work, after work we have loop+1 until next home or work

Comment: I see I made a mistake in my code. In the `replace` function `eating` should be `work`. I have updated my answer.

Comment: 4-th row must be 2, because it is after home. and shopping after work must be 3. please see edit in my post

Comment: Now I know what you are talking about. Please see my update.

Answer (score 0):

Another option using [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) assuming the first activity is always either home or work:

```
DT[, loop := shift(cumsum(activity %chin% c('home','work')), fill=1L), 
    .(household, persons)]
```

output:

```
    household persons activity loop
 1:         1       1     home    1
 2:         1       1 shopping    1
 3:         1       1     home    1
 4:         1       1   eating    2
 5:         1       1     work    2
 6:         1       1 shopping    3
 7:         1       1     home    3
 8:         1       2     home    1
 9:         1       2 shopping    1
10:         1       2     home    1
11:         2       1     home    1
12:         2       1   eating    1
13:         2       1     home    1
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("household   persons   activity
1       1        home
1       1         shopping
1       1        home
1       1         eating
1       1         work
1       1        shopping
1       1         home
1       2         home
1       2          shopping
1       2         home
2       1         home
2       1         eating
2       1         home")
```